# Randomly Generate A Color Similar To Another Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor, arc4random

In my app, I randomly generate a color via the following function:

```
UIColor *origionalRandomColor = [UIColor
                                   colorWithRed:arc4random_uniform(255) / 255.0
                                   green:arc4random_uniform(255) / 255.0
                                   blue:arc4random_uniform(255) / 255.0
                                   alpha:1.0];
```

And I want to generate a similar color to the above that is also random. I want to use a constant to determine how similar the new color is to the old color.

I've been trying to do this by first taking the `red` value, generating a small random number, and randomly choose to add or subtract it to form a new color. Then repeating the process for `green` and `blue`. And then I can reassemble the new similar color.

In the following code, `counter` is an `int`. When `counter` is a 1, I want the difference to be more pronounced than it is when counter is 20 for example.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
CGFloat red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0, alpha =0.0;
[origionalRandomColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];


//Randomly generates a 0 or 1
//0 results in subtracting - 1 results in adding the value
int AddSubtract = arc4random() %2;

//    double val = 20 - couter;
//    val = val/10 - 1;
//    if (val < .2) {
//        val = .2;
//    }

//    float x = (arc4random() % 100)/(float)100;
//    NSLog(@"**********%f", x);
//    x = x/((float)counter/100);
//    NSLog(@"----------%f", x);

float x = (20-counter)/10;
NSLog(@"----------%f", x);


if (AddSubtract == 0)   //subtract the val
    red -= x;
else                    //add the val
    red += x;

//Then repeated for green/blue

UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
```

The problem I'm having with the above is it that it is generating new colors that are drastically different than the original color. The original color will be a shade of green, and the new color will be a bright purple. When I `NSLog` the values, I'm getting crazy numbers, so clearly something is going awry.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the problem with the posted code? You explain what you want, you post code, but you don't say what the issue is.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "similar color". Simply shifting the RGB values pretty much means the colors won't be similar unless you only change one of the three. You are probably better off working with the HSB values. Perhaps a tiny change in hue and then varying changes in saturation and brightness would better suit your definition of "similar".

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://github.com/marzapower/MPColorTools. In particular, "Analogous colors".

Comment: Why not simply add `(arc4random_uniform(20f)-10f)/255f` to each color component? Additionally enclose the result into `fmax(0, fmin(1, x))` to ensure boundaries are fulfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
float x = (20-counter)/10;
```

Given counter is an int, (20-counter)/10 can only be 0, 1 or 2. 
You have to add a type-cast:

```
float x = (float)(20-counter) / 10;
```

or easier

```
float x = (20f - counter) / 10f;
```